# C# xslt BizTalk error object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, exception, biztalk, transform, xslt

I'm transforming xml using the following code.
It works fine for one xslt but it throws exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I have validated both xslt's they are working fine individually (meaning generating expected xml after transformation).
Can someone guide me to figure out what is wrong here. I did try to do some debug but can't get the error details or stack trace since it is a BizTalk app which is deployed on the server .... Thanks in advance
Here is the code.

```
 public static XmlDocument ApplyTransform(
       XmlDocument toTransform,
       XmlDocument StyleSheet)
   {
       XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
       XmlDocument transformedDoc = new XmlDocument();
       Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

       log4net.Ext.Serializable.SLog logger;
       logger = log4net.Ext.Serializable.SLogManager.GetLogger(@"BizTalk", typeof(RuntimeFileReader));
       logger.RegistryConfigurator();

       string logMsg = string.Format("StyleSheet used: {0}", StyleSheet);
       logger.Debug(logMsg);

       try
       {
           xslt.Load(StyleSheet);
           xslt.Transform(toTransform, null, sw);
           stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           transformedDoc.Load(stream);
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (sw != null)
           {
           sw.Flush();
           sw.Close();
           }
       }
       string gMsg = string.Format("xml after Transformation : {0}", transformedDoc.OuterXml);
       logger.Debug(gMsg);

       return transformedDoc;
   }
```

---

And here is the XSLT which throwing exception.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="Item"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" xml:space="default">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="errorCodes"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Biztalk Code:

```
PIToIMTransform = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();     
PIToIMTransform.Load(
                      gh.BizTalk.Components.RuntimeFileReader
                      .GetResourceFilePath("­PInode.xslt"));
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled) {
      xmlDoc = PIToIMTransform; 
      logger.DebugFormat(logProps, "XSLT being used for transform: {0}", xmlDoc.OuterXml);
}
xmlDoc = gh.BizTalk.Components
           .XmlUtility.ApplyTransform(PItransformedDoc, PIToIMTransform); 
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled){
       logger.DebugFormat(logProps, "PI Message AFTER removed errorCodes transform: {0}"
              , xmlDoc.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: Can you get access to the event logs on the Biztalk Server?

Comment: And has that block of code ever worked successfully inside of biztalk ?

Comment: @Nix. I have checked event logs no errors or warnings.

Comment: On the Biztalk Server there will be a log of the crash, you checked the System and the Application log ?

Comment: @Nix. Yes it is generating tranformed xml using the first XSLT but throwing exception on the second XSLT using the same code.

Comment: @Nix. Yes I have checked System and Application log. No errors and no warnings. And that is really puzzling me ... :-(

Comment: I have forgot to mention that when the next time it hit this code I do get the first logger.Debug(logMsg); but not hitting the second debug statment logger.Debug(gMsg);

Comment: I would almost guess you are crashing bc of the return null; statement.  What does your biztalk code do after the translate?   And are you using the same stylsheet both times?

Comment: It could be possible that it is throwing exception because of return null. But the question is why it is returning null if it is. We have custom exception handling so BizTalk generates an error message. No I'm using two different stylesheets.

Comment: Can you post(or explain if u are using a mapper) what your Biztalk code that is invoking the above, I would also suggest logging the exception in the catch block.

Comment: @Nix I'm not using a mapper. Here is the code I'm using in BizTalk. PIToIMTransform = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
PIToIMTransform.Load(gh.BizTalk.Components.RuntimeFileReader.GetResourceFilePath("PInode.xslt"));
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
{xmlDoc = PIToIMTransform; logger.DebugFormat(logProps, "XSLT being used for transform: {0}", xmlDoc.OuterXml);}
xmlDoc = gh.BizTalk.Components.XmlUtility.ApplyTransform(PItransformedDoc, PIToIMTransform);
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled){logger.DebugFormat(logProps, "PI Message AFTER removed errorCodes transform: {0}", xmlDoc.OuterXml);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get back to BizTalk you reference a null object and crash(the `xmlDoc.OuterXml`), xmlDoc is null and basically do a `null.OuterXml`:

```
mlDoc = gh.BizTalk.Components
       .XmlUtility.ApplyTransform(PItransformedDoc, PIToIMTransform); 
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled){
   logger.DebugFormat(logProps, "PI Message AFTER removed errorCodes transform: {0}"
          , xmlDoc.OuterXml);
}
```

Suggestion is to protect the xmlDoc call, and also print out in your exception handling block the exception that is being thrown.  Something is going wrong in your critical section it could be a parse error, it could be an xsl load error try this:

```
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       logger.Error(e);
       return ;
   }
```

And then let us know the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: & @Daniel thanks for your help.I have figured out the issue. I was using <xsl:strip-space> in the second XSLT. And that is causing the issue. Since with your help I was able to figure the issue so I will mark your response as an answer. Again Thanks for your help.